# Visited users count in ASP.NET without database

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I want to view my asp.net site visited count without using database.
The first idea is using something like `Application["VisitedUsersCount"]` and increasing it at `Session_Start` event of Application.
But the scope of this variable is Application and when I publish my site from visual studio this variable becomes zero again.

The second one is to using a file to save this variable and every time when `Session_Start` fired I open that file and increase its value. But the issue here is concurrency problem when two users want to access that file simultaneously. So my questions are:

1. Is there any concurrency problem to save this variable in file and accessing to it every time `Session_Start` fires?
2. Is it working if I just load this file on Application_Start and save it on `Application_End`? If I publish it from visual studio is the `Application_End` fires?

Comment: Waht you can do is go with first and integrate the file concept with it i.e. Whe you publish Application_Start executes get the file read the value and then set  Application["VisitedUsersCount"] to that value and in Application_End store the current value of  Application["VisitedUsersCount"]  back to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the second one. Therefore on `Application_Start` event I read that file and setting Application["VisitedUsersCount"] variable.Then on `Application_End` I write it again. The key point is that setting current file "Build Action" in "Properties" window to "None" to prevent changing current file on server for each publish.